Storage issue in batch process
We have developed a batch process to fetch entities and retrieve the necessary details. Given the large number of entities, the process handles them in chunks of 100. We are not storing the processed data in DB, we are just retrieving the details of the entity in batch. However, We have observed that a significant amount of storage is consumed during batch processing, and this storage is not released after each batch completes. This issue leads to storage becoming full after several batch executions.
We also checked the batch process provided by the core system (such as publishing/unpublishing nodes), but the storage issue persists.
Since we are using Lando to containerize the project, storage is only freed when the project is destroyed. The same issue occurs in a non-Lando setup.
Any idea why this is being caused or any solution to this?
Thank You

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This question needs "storage" defined to a level of technical detail suitable to provide a factual answer.

This is a comment from @clive in Why does this code use so much memory?

It’s not a leak as such - nodes are statically cached when they’re
loaded. Load enough of them and the static cache will fill up the
available memory. You can use EntityStorageBase::resetCache to
alleviate the problem

So most likely the solution to your problem is resetCache()

I am referring to hard drive storage, the depleted memory is never allocated back, even when using resetCache() method, or clearing the cache doesn't help.
